# Get public Ip Address of Google App engine Project

Tags: google-app-engine, ip

I hosted my project at www.example.appspot.com and I want to register for a service that required my public Ip address. How do i get the IP address of my app engine project. Thanks.

Comment: can you provide more details? how it required? you can get IP addresses from `host www.yourodmain.com`, that you could use for registration. but you must understand that it's an ephemeral address, can be changed any time (and most likely you'll get few different IPs)

Answer (score 1):

You can use any DNS lookup tool to get the address of the host.

For example on linux you'd get something along these lines:

```
$ nslookup www.example.appspot.com
...
Non-authoritative answer:
www.example.appspot.com     canonical name = appspot.l.google.com.
Name:   appspot.l.google.com
Address: 216.58.219.241
$ host www.example.appspot.com
www.example.appspot.com is an alias for appspot.l.google.com.
appspot.l.google.com has address 216.58.219.241
appspot.l.google.com has IPv6 address 2607:f8b0:4006:80e::2011
appspot.l.google.com mail is handled by 10 alt1.gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com.
appspot.l.google.com mail is handled by 40 alt4.gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com.
appspot.l.google.com mail is handled by 5 gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com.
appspot.l.google.com mail is handled by 30 alt3.gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com.
appspot.l.google.com mail is handled by 20 alt2.gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com.
```

Comment: The address will be shared by many/all GAE apps and possibly other Google services, this is expected. If you want a dedicated IP for your app it's possible as well: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl#purchase_a_vip

Answer (score 1):

Google AppEngine doesn't have a single IP. It runs on Google's network on very large number of machines over different regions and therefore it has many IP addresses (or ranges).

Here is how you can find these ranges:

Run `dig -t txt _cloud-netblocks.googleusercontent.com`

Partial list of CIDR blocks is:
`8.34.208.0/20
8.35.192.0/21
8.35.200.0/23
23.236.48.0/20
23.251.128.0/19
107.167.160.0/19
107.178.192.0/18
108.170.192.0/20
108.170.208.0/21
108.170.216.0/22
108.170.220.0/23
108.170.222.0/24
108.59.80.0/20
130.211.4.0/22
146.148.16.0/20
146.148.2.0/23
146.148.32.0/19
146.148.4.0/22
146.148.64.0/18
146.148.8.0/21
162.216.148.0/22
162.222.176.0/21
173.255.112.0/20
192.158.28.0/22
199.192.112.0/22
199.223.232.0/22
199.223.236.0/23`

Answer (score 0):

A more updated (April 2018) answer based on what I went through today to launch [pixler.io](http://www.pixler.io/) is as follows:

In Google Cloud Platform go to your App Engine and click on "settings", from there you will have to go to "Custom Domains" and add your domain.

[image]

You will be asked to [verify your domain by adding a TEXT record](https://support.google.com/a/answer/183895?hl=en). After you do that, you will see the IP addresses populated in the "Data" column, you can copy that into your A record

[image]